# How to count duplicates of words/do case insensitive comparisons in user inputted text?

Tags: java

Positive words are considered: "good" or "awesome and negative words are considered: "bad" or "terrible". I want to count every time a positive or negative word is used and add it to the total pos/neg counts. The issue with the present code is it fails to count duplicates. What logic can i use to efficiently return the tallies for pos and neg words? In addition how can i disregard the case of the user input?

```
package practice;

import java.io.*;

public class SentimentAnalyser {

    public static String analyse(String text) {     
       int posCount = 0;
       int negCount = 0;
       String positive = "good";
       String pos1 = "awesome";
       String negative = "bad";
       String neg1 = "terrible";

       if(text.contains(positive) | text.contains(pos1)){
           posCount++;
       }

       if(text.contains(negative) | text.contains(neg1)){
           negCount++;
       }

       String res = Integer.toString(posCount);
       String res1 = Integer.toString(negCount);
       String result = (posCount+"P"+negCount+"N");

       return result;                       
    }


    public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException {
       BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       System.out.println("Enter the text with spaces(press enter to done):");
       String text=br.readLine();

       System.out.println("Line:\n"+analyse(text));     
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question? I see a requirement and some (formerly) poorly formatted code.

Comment: Well, I don't know. What's wrong with your current code? And have you done any debugging of your own?

Comment: It fails to count duplicates amongst other things. If you don't know why comment? I need a more efficient way of achieving this if anyone has the capacity to empathize with my being a beginner & this being the first post i've created

Comment: Because this is information that you should have included from the start. "Questions" which consist of "Here's what I need to do, here's my code, someone debug this for me" are typically *not* too well-received. A good question would display 1) research/debugging effort, 2) explain *exactly* what is wrong with the existing code as well as any alternatives made, 3) exactly what input/output you expect and get, among other requirements. I'm sorry that you seem to think I am incapable of empathy, but I'm trying to help you write a question that's more likely to get answered.

Comment: And again, have you done any debugging of your own? "This question does not show any research effort" is a downvote reason, and it's not uncommon for lack of debuggging effort to be taken as lack of research effort too.

Comment: I have edited the wording of this post if anyone has additional or more efficient logic to implement this program.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first convert the input String to lowercase to make the check case-insensitive. Then you can use a simple [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) to count the matches of the words:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

...

public static String analyse(String text) {
   text = text.toLowerCase();
   int posCount = 0;
   int negCount = 0;
   String positive = "good|awesome";
   String negative = "bad|terrible";

   Pattern positivePattern = Pattern.compile(positive);
   Pattern negativePattern = Pattern.compile(negative);

   Matcher matcher = positivePattern.matcher(text);
   while(matcher.find()) {
       posCount++;
   }
   matcher = negativePattern.matcher(text);
   while(matcher.find()) {
       negCount++;
   }

   String res = Integer.toString(posCount);
   String res1 = Integer.toString(negCount);
   String result = (posCount+"P"+negCount+"N");

   return result;                       
}
```

P.S.: In your original code, you should use the conditional OR operator `||` instead of the bitwise operator `|`.

Comment: This is direct and helpful. I presume this requires an import?

Comment: Well obviously for the `Pattern` and `Matcher`. Will update it.

Comment: Cool. & why logical operator instead of bitwise if only checking for one or the other?

Comment: The single pipe `|` in the regular expression pattern `good|awesome` means either `good` or `awesome`, i.e. it is the logical OR operator in regex terminology. In Java, however, the logical OR is `||`.